# Collapsible menu always open when page loads

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm using the below script attached to a HTML menu, but it is loading fully open on the page.
The whole menu tree collapses when a header is clicked on, and opens as expected.

Can anybody tell me if there is something in here that is the problem?

```
function toggleMenu(objID) {
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    var i = 1;
    while (document.getElementById('menu' + i)) {
        var ob = document.getElementById('menu' + i).nextSibling;
        ob = ob.style ? ob.style : ob.nextSibling.style;
        if (objID == 'menu' + i) ob.display = (ob.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
        else ob.display = 'none';
        i++;
    }
}
var i = 1;
while (document.getElementById('menu' + i)) {
    document.getElementById('menu' + i).onclick = new Function("toggleMenu('menu" + i + "')");
    i++
}
```

Comment: please use proper formatting for the code: put it into a code block and indent it

Comment: Can you show us the HTML and CSS for the menu too? The menu may not be set to be display: none at the start?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a non-JavaScript solution?

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/nrAPu/